# Object of class Town could not be converted to string on Cakephp 2.10.24

Tags: php, cakephp

I have this program that I upgraded from cakephp 2.2 to cakephp 2.10.24 to support php7.4. When I try to add a new Town entry I get the following error:

```
Object of class Town could not be converted to string
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Stack Trace
APP/Controller/TownsController.php line 61 → CommonComponent->_saveEntity()
            $this->Town->set($data);
            
            if ($this->Town->validates()) {
                $this->Common->_saveEntity($data, 'Town', "Town {$data['Town']['name']} was created.");
                return $this->redirect("/admin/towns");
[internal function] → TownsController->admin_add()
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 499 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs()
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 193 → Controller->invokeAction()
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 167 → Dispatcher->_invoke()
APP/webroot/index.php line 92 → Dispatcher->dispatch()
```

TownsController.php

```
    function admin_add() {
                
        if ($this->Common->_isRequest('post put') && ($data = $this->request->data)) {
            $this->Town->set($data);
            
            if ($this->Town->validates()) {
                $this->Common->_saveEntity($data, 'Town', "Town {$data['Town']['name']} was created."); //line 61
                return $this->redirect("/admin/towns");
            }
        }
    }
```

CommonComponent.php

```
    function _saveEntity($data=array(), $modelClass="", $flash_message=null) {
        if (empty($modelClass) && isset($this->controller->modelClass)) {
            $modelClass = $this->controller->modelClass;
        }
        if (empty($modelClass)) {
            $keys = array_keys($data);
            $modelClass = $keys[0];
        }
        $model =& $this->_getEntity($modelClass);

        try {
            $model->id = null;
            // $model->recursive = -1;
            $saved = $model->save($data, false);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            if ($flash_message !== false) {
                $this->Session->setFlash("Unable to save $model.", 'default', array('class' => 'error'));
            }
            return false;
        }
        if ($flash_message === null) {
            $op = Hash::check($data, "$modelClass.id") ? 'updated' : 'created';
            $flash_message = "$modelClass {". $modelClass . ".title} was $op.";
        }
        if ($flash_message) {
            $this->_extractAndReplace($flash_message);
            $this->Session->setFlash($flash_message, 'default', array('class' => 'success'));
        }
        return $saved;
    }
```

However, I can create a new entry for Provinces and Countries with a similar implementation found on `TownsController.php admin_add()` without having the error `Object of class Town could not be converted to string`.

Please advice, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
$this->Session->setFlash("Unable to save $model.", 'default', array('class' => 'error'));
```

You are using the `$model` variable - which is supposed to be an object - as a String. which throws an error in PHP.

According to your code, most-likely you need to use the `$modelClass`

```
$this->Session->setFlash("Unable to save $modelClass.", 'default', array('class' => 'error'));
```

Comment: Use a proper IDE, e.g. PHPStorm would tell you right away :) With a big yellow underlining on the variable. Also PHPStan would, if you let it check your code - which you should.